# Gradle 6.5 and Java 14 - IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert string value 'VERSION_14' to an enum value of type

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I am using Windows7, STS 4.6.2 , Gradle 6.5 and OpenJDK 14.
When creating a new Spring Started project with the following settings

[image]
[image]

The Following error occurs.

IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert string value 'VERSION_14' to an enum value of type 'org.gradle.api.JavaVersion' (valid case insensitive values: VERSION_1_1, VERSION_1_2, VERSION_1_3, VERSION_1_4, VERSION_1_5, VERSION_1_6, VERSION_1_7, VERSION_1_8, VERSION_1_9, VERSION_1_10, VERSION_11, VERSION_12, VERSION_13, VERSION_HIGHER)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Works fine with Java 11.I have checked and the compiled class inside the lib folder of Gradle : org.gradle.api.JavaVersion , contains the enum VERSION_14, not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: @michalk, you are right, my bad.

Comment: I don't use STS, but it appears you need to update the Buildship plugin to 3.1.4 to get support for Java 14. Here is the issue that describes it: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/979

Comment: @BjørnVester Thanks a lot. This solved the issue for me.I had updated the STS Gradle Plugin and it worked fine